# How to fit images in Wordpress gallery

Tags: wordpress

When I use a Wordpress gallery shortcode [gallery columns="3" size="medium" link="none" ids="13,14,11,16,18,19"] it displays a 3 column gallery but the images heights don’t match on each row, and it leaves ugly space below panoramic images.

How can I get it so that the height of all images on each row is the same, even if it automatically crops away some of the sides of each image?

Comment: You can do that by using CSS.

Comment: When editing your Gallery in the WordPress interface, there's an option to set the image size. By default, Medium, Large, and Full Size image sizes do not crop images. Thumbnail will crop them. If you want to have a specific image size (example, 800px by 600px with cropping) you'll want to take a look at WordPress's custom image sizes feature. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

Comment: I need to use the shortcode to dynamically create a gallery.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the default wordpress gallery markup you can override the display by adding these css classes:

We're defining a fixed aspect ratio for wrapping gallery divs and using `object-fit:` to fill the frame.

In this example we are using a square ratio.

```css
.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin: 3em 0 3em -0.8em;
    width: 100%;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.gallery-item{
    width:33.333%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0.3em;
}


/* aspect ratio hack*/
.gallery-icon {
    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:100%;
    /* use 56.25% for 16/9 ration */
}

.gallery-icon a,
.gallery-icon img
 {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0; 
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%
}

/* prevent distortions */
.gallery-icon img{
    object-fit:cover;
    object-position: 50%
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-716 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-thumbnail">

<figure class="gallery-item">
    <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
        <img width="200" height="400" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x400" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt="thumb" >
    </div>
</figure>


<figure class="gallery-item">
    <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
        <img width="300" height="400" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt="thumb" >
    </div>
</figure>


<figure class="gallery-item">
    <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
        <img width="200" height="400" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x100" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt="thumb" >
    </div>
</figure>


<figure class="gallery-item">
    <div class="gallery-icon landscape">
        <img width="200" height="400" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt="thumb" >
    </div>
</figure>


</div>
```

You could also use css property `aspect-ratio:` but it's still not widely supported.